# how to import data files from s3 to postgresql rds

Tags: postgresql, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am very new to AWS, and Postgresql.

1. I have created a Postgresql db (using rds on aws)
2. I have uploaded several documents to multiple s3 buckets
3. I have a EC2 (Amazon Linux 64 bit) running

I tried to use a data pipeline, but nothing seems to be available (template) for Postgres.  I can't figure out how to connect to my RDS instance and import/export data from postgres.

I assumed that I could use EC2 to grab from my S3 bucket and import into Postgres in lieu of no data pipeline template being available.  If it is possible I have no idea how..  Please advise if possible..

Comment: Ideally Amazon would want to extend the `COPY` command to support S3 URLs for file paths, but I won't be surprised if for now you have to fetch the data from S3 via a client that then feeds it to PostgreSQL via `COPY`.

Comment: Yes, with RDS, you will generally need to load from an EC2 instance. Only the custom database systems like Redshift tend to allow direct loading from s3.

Comment: Thank you both.  Can either of you provide any examples on how to accomplish this?  I am able to connect EC2 to S3 and EC2 to RDS.  I have an idea on how to pull the file from S3 down to EC2, but at that point I have no idea how to load the file from EC2 into the Postgresql DB (running on res). Please help or point me to instructions.  I have been searching online for several days now..

Answer (score 34):

S3 -> RDS direct load is now possible for PostgreSQL Aurora and RDS PostgreSQL >= 11.1 as `aws_s3` extension.

- [Amazon Aurora with PostgreSQL Compatibility Supports Data Import from Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/06/amazon-aurora-with-postgresql-compatibility-supports-data-import-from-amazon-s3/)
- [Amazon RDS for PostgreSQL Now Supports Data Import from Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/04/amazon-rds-postgresql-supports-data-import-from-amazon-s3/)

Parameters are similar to those of [PostgreSQL COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) command

```
psql=> SELECT aws_s3.table_import_from_s3(
 'table_name', '', '(format csv)',
 'BUCKET_NAME', 'path/to/object', 'us-east-2'
);
```

Be warned that this feature does not work for older versions.

Comment: Can you please provide the steps? The AWS Documentation is a little unclear, few are in psql and few are normal commands, where to run those? In cmd? The PSQL command given by you here, how will it understand which table to load to?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL.Procedural.Importing.html

Comment: do you know how to handle an empty csv while loading via this S3 import. 
cause I have a scenario where loading CSV file is automated from S3 to postgres RDS. sometimes I end up getting empty csv. This lead to connection failure .

Answer (score 27):

I wish AWS extends COPY command in RDS Postgresql as they did in Redshift. But for now they haven't and we have to do it by ourselves.

1. Install `awscli` on your EC2 box (it might have been installed by default)
2. Configure your `awscli` with credentials
3. Use `aws s3 sync` or `aws s3 cp` commmands to download from s3 to your local directory
4. Use psql command to `\COPY` the files into your RDS (requires `\` to copy from client directory)

Example:

```
aws s3 cp s3://bucket/file.csv /mydirectory/file.csv
psql -h your_rds.amazonaws.com -U username -d dbname -c '\COPY table FROM ''file.csv'' CSV HEADER'
```

Comment: Is this still actual, or has Amazon updated Redshifts' functionality by now? I have the exact same question, except that I need to automate this and import files (.csv) from S3 on a weekly basis into my PostGresql RDS Instance

Comment: RDS PostgreSQL is based on community PostgreSQL and community PostgreSQL COPY statement does not support COPY FROM/TO S3 in current versions. 

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-copy.html

Comment: This is no longer true, RDS now supports the COPY comamnd from S3 via the `aws_s3` extension. See the answer from @quiver below.

Answer (score 13):

The prior answers have been superseded by more recent events at AWS.

There is now excellent support for S3-to-RDS-database loading via the Data Pipeline service (which can be used for many other data conversion tasks too, this is just one example).

This AWS article is for S3-to-RDS-MySQL.  Should be very similar for RDS-Postgres.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-template-copys3tords.html

Comment: Can anybody actually confirm that this works into RDS Postgres?  It's actually not at all clear from the documentation Chris links whether S3-to-Postgres is supported.

Comment: "AWS Data Pipeline Support for all Amazon RDS Databases Now Available" https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2015/08/aws-data-pipeline-support-for-all-amazon-rds-databases-now-available/

Answer (score 0):

if you can launch the psql client and connect to RDS on EC2 instance, you should be able to use the following command:

\copy customer_orders from 'myfile.csv' with DELIMITER ','

Comment: That operates on local files, not files on S3.