# Syntax error importing data from S3 into Amazon RDS using SQL

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I have a 5GB CSV file stored in S3. I have a PostgreSQL database on Amazon RDS set to only allow access from my IP address. I'm accessing it from my Postgres client (Postico).

I'm trying to upload data with the instructions on the AWS site (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_loading-tables-from-s3.html)

I have a user with unlimited access to S3 and RDS. Specifically, they have the AmazonS3FullAccess and AmazonRDSFullAccess policies.

I'm using this code:

```
COPY schema.table FROM 's3://(filled_in_with_bucket_name)/file.csv'
access_key_id 'aws_access_key_id=(filled_in_with_access_key)'
secret_access_key 'aws_secret_access_key=(filled_in_with_secret_key)'
CSV;
```

I get this error ERROR:  syntax error at or near "access_key_id"

I have also tried variants with

```
COPY schema.table FROM 's3://(filled_in_with_bucket_name)/file.csv'
WITH CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=(filled_in_with_access_key);aws_secret_access_key=(filled_in_with_secret_key)'
  CSV;'

COPY schema.table FROM 's3://(filled_in_with_bucket_name)/file.csv'
CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=(filled_in_with_access_key);aws_secret_access_key=(filled_in_with_secret_key)'
  CSV;'
```

These serve: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CREDENTIALS"

Comment: Postgres is not the same as Redshift!, which one do you have? The link and command are for Redshift only. you cannot do that with postgres. Loading data from S3 to postgres is not possible directly. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20257226/how-to-import-data-files-from-s3-to-postgresql-rds

Comment: Command looks ok. Is there a chance of any hidden character before access_key_id? If you have copy pasted this from somewhere, can you please try typing part of command starting from s3:// up to access_key_id.

Comment: @nitzien I think (as i posted above) that its a more fundamental problem ! however the OP has not responded to my question yet.

Comment: Have you tried this.

COPY schema.table FROM 's3://(filled_in_with_bucket_name)/file.csv'   
access_key_id 'filled_in_with_access_key'   
secret_access_key 'filled_in_with_secret_key'   
CSV;

Comment: Thanks for your help. You're right @JonScott, I mixed up Postgres and Redshift. I used that PSQL command and it worked like a charm.

Comment: @Sebastian - so for the benefit of anyone else looking at this question, which is it; PostgreSQL or Redshift?

Comment: Thanks @Nathan. I'm using Postgres Amazon RDS. I learned, from this, the copy command does not work, but PSQL command does.