# How do I batch process my R machine learning model?

Tags: python, r, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an R script for a random forest classification model. I connected my R instance to my redshift postgres database with `RPostgreSQL` and then ran a series of data transformation and model commands, using the `caret` library.

My model assigns a score to every user. I've been running the model on my own and uploading the data s3 and then [transferring it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20257226/how-to-import-data-files-from-s3-to-postgresql-rds) to postgres with `\copy`

I'd like to automate the process. All the queries stay the same every time, including the R script to build the model, but the underlying data changes and so I want to make sure my model is calculating from the most up to date data and then rewriting the `scores` table.

I was going to use `AWS lambda` and set up a cron job, but the model takes more than 300 seconds. Instead, I'm thinking about this architecture:

1- Write a script that triggers the R job to run with a curl request. It would cause the R script to download the new data and create the model with a rest API through  [`plumbR`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plumber/plumber.pdf)

2- Have the R API return the new `scores` as a JSON object and then use the Python script to upload the scores to `s3` and then`\copy` them over to redshift postgres.

3- Set up a cron job on AWS elastic beanstalk to trigger this every Monday,

Could that work? Can I use AWS beanstalk to set up a python script to run automatically and, if so, does that mean I need an ec2 instance running 24/7?

Comment: `redshiftTools` package has `rs_replace_table` function that allows uploading data to s3 and then copy it to redshift. So if you include this in your R script then you don't need to use python to upload to s3 and copy?